# Method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

*Context: I am really scratching my head with this one, I've had a look at other code to see how this is done. I appreciate this is a fundamentally simple part of coding. To be honest up until now I've probably overused class methods, but self.attrib = x doesn't work with class methods. Anyway, my problem.*

I have this in my model:

```
  def self.get_user
    @people = Person.where(:mp => nil)
    @people.each do |person|
      person.get_link(person.postcode)
    end
  end

  def get_link(postcode)
    base = "http://news.bbc.co.uk/democracylive/hi/search?q="
    postcode = postcode
    target = "//a[starts-with(@class, 'name')]  /@href"
    url = base + postcode
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    mps = []
    page.xpath(target).each do |node|
      mps << node.text
    end
    link = mps[0]
    self.get_email(link, postcode)
  end
```

Now the person.get_link(person.postcode) part throws up a no method found error in the console :/ I literally don't understand why, its clearly there. The only thing I can think of is that the data type is incorrect - problem is I don't know how to correct that.

Really appreciate any pointers.

(Note: I know that method might not be the best it can be, I'm a bit of a noob but am getting there - slowly but surely :) )

EDIT: ADDED STACK TRACE

NoMethodError: undefined method `get_link' for #<Person:0x103633cc0>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:367:in`method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/geoff/RailsWork/mpmail/app/models/postcode.rb:8:in`get_user'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in`**send**'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/geoff/RailsWork/mpmail/app/models/postcode.rb:7:in`get_user'
    from (irb):2

Comment: What is the class these methods are in?

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: @Mark Thomas - class is Postcode.rb

Comment: @ Chris McCauley - think I've added the right thing to the OP.

Comment: Try this in Rails console:

person = Person.new; person.respond_to? :get_link

Comment: @Skilldrick
>> person = Person.new; person.respond_to? :get_link
=> false

Comment: Can you show us the complete class? I think the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: @Geoff, so you've defined get_link for a Postcode object, and you expect it to be available for your Person objects?

Comment: Looks like you have too much coupling between your models. Try making them independent (i.e. don't refer to Person from your Postcode model).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the get_link method on the Person class while you defined it in the Postcode class, if I'm reading your stacktrace correctly. Move get_link to the Person-class and see what happens.

Comment: Doh! Completely missed that. That's why it's helpful to see the whole class :)